# Deserialization of given data in Win8App

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization, deserialization

I have a Win8App and a WCF. The Win8App makes different calls and the WCF delivers `List` and `ObservableCollections` of custom classes like `Person` in the examples below. My Problem was that every list or collection was empty (not null) when it arrives in my Win8App. I found out it was about deserialization but what to do now?

I wrote some Testcode with `List`, `Array`, `ObservableCollection` and `IList` or just a single object and i never got an Exception but always empty (not null) collections or an empty single object. Is it a deserialization problem or configuration problem of my WCF/Win8App?

WCF IService.cs:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{       
    [OperationContract(Name = "GetPerson")]
    Person GetPerson();

    [OperationContract(Name = "GetPersons")]
    List<Person> GetPersons();

    [OperationContract(Name = "GetPersonArray")]
    Person[] GetPersonArray();

    [OperationContract(Name = "GetPersonList")]
    IList<Person> GetPersonList();

    [OperationContract(Name = "GetPersonCollection")]
    ObservableCollection<Person> GetPersonCollection();        
}
```

WCF .svc:

```
public Person GetPerson()
{
    return new Person() { Name = "asdf", IstZeit = new TimeSpan(10000000) };
}

public List<Person> GetPersons()
{
    List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
    {
        list.Add(new Person() { Name = "asdf", IstZeit = new TimeSpan(10000000) });

    }
    return list;
}


public ObservableCollection<Person> GetPersonCollection()
{
    ObservableCollection<Person> list = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
    {
        list.Add(new Person() { Name = "asdf", IstZeit = new TimeSpan(10000000) });

    }
    return list;
}

public Person[] GetPersonArray()
{
   List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
   for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
   {
       list.Add(new Person() { Name = "asdf", IstZeit = new TimeSpan(10000000) });

   }
   return list.ToArray();
}

public IList<Person> GetPersonList()
{
    List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
    {
        list.Add(new Person() { Name = "asdf", IstZeit = new TimeSpan(10000000) });

    }
    return list;
}
```

WCF - Class Person

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    private string name;
    private string email;
    private TimeSpan istZeit;

    public Person()
    {

    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public TimeSpan IstZeit
    {
        get { return istZeit; }
        set { istZeit = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
        set { email = value; }
    }
}
```

---

Now my Win8App.....

Setting ServiceReference via ChannelFactory:

```
public static IMyService GetClientForService()
{
    EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:12345/Service1.svc");

    BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();     

    ChannelFactory<IMyService> channelFactory = channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress);
    IMyService client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();            

    return client;
}
```

In my Win8App i implemented same code for `IMyService` and `Person` like in WCF.

This Method is calling the WCF:

```
private void CheckWCFMethods()
{
    IMyService client = ServiceBinding.GetClientForService();

    var p = client.GetPerson();
    IList<Person> iList = client.GetPersonList();
    ObservableCollection<Person> collection = client.GetPersonCollection();
    Person[] array = client.GetPersonArray();
    List<Person> list = client.GetPersons();

    #if(DEBUG)
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("SinglePersonName:{0}\niList.Count:{1}\nCollection.Count:{2}\nArray.Length:{3}\nList.Count:{4}",string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Name) ? "empty" : p.Name, iList.Count, collection.Count, array.Length, list.Count));
    Debug.WriteLine("DONE");
    #endif
}
```

Result of debugging is always:

```
**DEBUGRESULT**
SinglePersonName:empty
IList.Count:0
Collection.Count:0
Array.Length:0
List.Count:0
DONE
```

but when i execute the WCF directly via WCF-Testclient i got:

```
SinglePersonName: asdf
IList.Count:19
Collection.Count:19
Array.Length:19
List.Count:19
```

---

---

I've tried to set `[KnownType]` and `[ServiceKnownType]` (server- and clientside) and it doesn't change anything. I've only written 2 or 3 WCF before but never had to handle deserializationproblems because when i set the ServiceReference via Visual Studio the Collection type and Dictionary collection type is set automatically (or by simple clicks). So i'm new to ChannelFactory and new to this serialization coding on serverside and clientside.

What can and what should i do to deserialize the data in my Win8App?

---

if you need any further information please let me know!

---

** **EDIT** **

So i've tried to set a namespace to the person class on client side (`class Person` is in a Folder called "DataContracts" in my TestWCF):

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://localhost:12345/DataContracts")]
public class Person{}
```

but the results still look like this:

```
**DEBUGRESULT**
SinglePersonName:empty
IList.Count:0
Collection.Count:0
Array.Length:0
List.Count:0
DONE
```

---

** **EDIT** **

so i tried a few things with my a windows 8.1 test application and it confuses me that a normal visual studio service reference is doing well while my channelfactory "reference" is doing nothing - can't figure out whats so wrong with it:
[image]

i'm really confused and if you want to try it by yourself you can download this sample wcf and w8.1app here (my googledrive):
[Testfiles](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxgs-zup7ypLY1oxYi1ZMmp4VTA/view?usp=sharing)

you just have to set the uri for the endpointadress in the win8.1 application and start the wcf (or publish on iis).

any further informations to this theme?

Comment: When you say "In my Win8App i implemented same code for IMyService and Person like in WCF", did you copy/paste the data contract and service contract definitions from the service to your client application?

Comment: @carlosfigueira - yes i've created a class where the interface is implemented and all needed classes? not correct? Just did it like google told me to do - how else should i implement the service interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copied / pasted the data / service contracts as is, then you're likely getting a XML namespace mismatch. When the XML that goes over the wire in the WCF requests / responses, its elements are within certain XML namespaces. When you define a `[DataContract]` or a `[ServiceContract]` without specifying explicitly which XML namespace to use, WCF will default to a namespace derived from the namespace of the class itself (i.e., its CLR namespace).

If you have two classes, one on the client, and one on the server for the data contract, but they're in different CLR namespaces (say, `MyApp.Service.Person` and `MyApp.Client.Person`), then the XML that is used by WCF that corresponds to those classes are different.

If this is indeed the case, try defining explicitly the namespace on your data contract, so that this mismatch won't happen anymore:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://my.company.com/contracts")]
public class Person
{
    private string name;
    private string email;
    private TimeSpan istZeit;

    public Person()
    {

    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public TimeSpan IstZeit
    {
        get { return istZeit; }
        set { istZeit = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
        set { email = value; }
    }
}
```

Another alternative would be to use a tool such as the "Add Service Reference" on Visual Studio on your client project, pointing it to the service metadata (if you have it enabled). The tool will create the classes to be used in the client with the appropriate namespace declarations.

Comment: Because of the "Add Service Reference" - that's my problem. i've modified the WCF with `BasicHTTPAuthentification` and wasn't able to add a reference because i've to authenticate about 100 times before it throws an error. That's why i want to add the "reference" via ChannelFactory. Authentification works fine but now i've the (de-)serialization problems with custom classes and generic lists and collections.
I'll try it with the namespace attribute but does this attribute help with the lists and collections?

Comment: and how would my namespace look as an URL? Would `[DataContract(Namespace = "http://localhost:port/Service1.svc")]` be enough or do i have to specify in which folder in the wcf the classes are?

Comment: Updated my Question - added namespace on client side to `class Person` but it didn't change a thing. Do i have to set `[KnownType]` or `[ServiceKnownType]` anywhere?

Comment: I looked at the .zip file that you linked from your updated question; the `[DataContract]` attribute in the class `Person` on the server side does not have any `Namespace` defined (so it will take a default value, something like `"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService1.DataContracts"`), while on the client side you have it. Try defining *the same namespace on both the client and the server versions of the class*, and this should start working.

Comment: THANK YOU! Setting the namespace on both sides solved my problem. Now i have to classify/reorder/adjust the original WCF and Win8App coding. So if i set namespaces to every custom class it should work. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You should mark an intarface with a `[ServiceContract]` attribute

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
```

Comment: sorry my fault - i have set this attribute. forgot to write it in the example code here!

Answer (score 0):

Today I ran into an issue where the serializer choked trying to deserialize timespans.  In my case removing the timespan from the object to be serialized fixed the problem.  I was able to replace the timespan with an integer (number of seconds), not sure if that will work for you, but it might be something to check.

Comment: thanks for your answer but it didn't help! I recommend carlosfigueiras answer - setting the namespace on server and client side was the solution.